Recursive formula for multi-dimensional Gaussian integrals
Question: I have been trying to find a general formula for Gaussian integrals of the form
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_{-\infty}^0...\int_{-\infty}^0\left[\phi(z_n-z_{n-1})\phi(z_{n-1}-z_{n-2})...\phi(z_2-z_1)\phi(z_1)\right]dz_n dz_{n-1}... dz_1,
\end{align}
where where $\phi(\cdot)$ is a pdf of a standard normal distribution, that is,
\begin{align}
\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}
\end{align}
and $I_1$ is defined as
\begin{align}
 I_1 =\int_{-\infty}^0\phi(z_1)dz_1
\end{align}
For low values of $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it is possible (though tedious) to compute the value of $I_n$ by repeatedly applying integration by parts if one knows the values of $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{n-1}$ (see my computations below).
These integrals have probabilistic interpretation. Let $\{Z_n\}_{n=1}^N$ be a sequence of standard normal variables and define $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$. Then, the probability that $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$ are all less than $0$ is given by $I_n$.  Thus, there might be a way to compute these integrals using martingale theory, though I was not able to find such a way.

My work (overview): I have computed analytically these integrals for $n\leq 6$ (below I described the approach used) and verified my calculations numerically. These calculations suggest that the family of integrals $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies the following recursion
\begin{align}
\frac{I_n}{I_{n-1}}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}
\end{align}
As mentioned above, for low values of $n$, one can verify that by simply computing these integrals. I have been trying to establish that formula for any $n$ using induction, but without a success.
Another approach I tried using is by applying martingale theory to compute the probability that the running maximum of a martingale $X$ (as defined above) is less than $0$ for $k\in{1,...,n}$. But I could not find a way around the need to compute these integrals to get any answers.

My work (details): (Case $n=2$): Computing $I_2$ is straightforward. We have
\begin{align}
I_2 = &\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(z_2-z_1)\phi(z_1)dz_2dz_1\\
    = &\int_{-\infty}^0 \left[\Phi(z_2 - z_1)\right]_{-\infty}^0\phi(z_1)dz_1\\
    = &\int_{-\infty}^0 \Phi(- z_1)\phi(z_1)dz_1\\
    = &\int_{-\infty}^0 [1-\Phi(z_1)]\phi(z_1)dz_1\\
    = &\frac{1}{2} - \int_{-\infty}^0\Phi(z_1)\phi(z_1)dz_1
\end{align}
Define
\begin{align}
J_2 = \int_{-\infty}^0\Phi(z_1)\phi(z_1)dz_1
\end{align}
Applying integration by parts, we can see that
\begin{align}
J_2 = \left[\Phi^2(z_1)\right]_{-\infty}^0 - \int_{-\infty}^0\Phi(z_1)\phi(z_1)dz_1 = \frac{1}{4} - J_2  \;\;\; \bigg( =\frac{1}{2}I_1 - J_2 \bigg)
\end{align}
implying that $J_2=\frac{1}{8}$ and so $I_2=\frac{3}{8}$. We see that
\begin{align}
\frac{I_2}{I_1} = \frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{3}{4} 
\end{align}
which agrees with the conjecture that $I_n/I_{n-1} = (2n-1)/2n$.
(Case $n=3$)
One can follows the same approach to compute $I_3$. As in the case $n=2$, we begin by evaluating the inner-most integral in $I_3$, to obtain
\begin{align}
I_3 = I_2 - J_3,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
J_3 = \int_{-\infty}^0\Phi(z_2)\phi(z_2-z_1)\phi(z_1)dz_2dz_1
\end{align}
and by applying integration by parts twice, one obtains
\begin{align}
J_3 = \frac{1}{2}I_2 -  \frac{1}{2}J_2 - J_3
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
J_3 = \frac{1}{4}I_2 - \frac{1}{4}J_2 = \frac{3}{32}-\frac{1}{32} =\frac{1}{16}
\end{align}
It follows that $I_3=\frac{5}{16}$.
We can now compute $I_3/I_2$ to see that it is equal to
\begin{align}
\frac{I_3}{I_2} = \frac{\frac{5}{16}}{\frac{3}{8}} = \frac{5}{6},
\end{align}
which again agrees with the conjecture $I_n/I_{n-1}=(2n-1)/2n$
(Cases $n>3$):
The above strategy of repeated application of integration by parts can be used for any $n$, but it quickly gets very tedious. I did it analytically and verified my calculations using numerical integration for $n=4,5,6$. In particular, $I_4 =35/128$, $I_5=63/256$, and $I_6=231/1024$.
In general, we have
\begin{align}
I_n = I_{n-1}-J_n
\end{align}
and, by repeated application of integration by parts
\begin{align}
 J_n = \frac{1}{2} I_{n-1} - I_{n-2}J_2 - I_{n-2}J_3 ... -I_{2}J_{n-2}-\frac{1}{2}J_{n-1} - J_n
\end{align}
Remark [Mapping $I_n$ to joint CDF]
To see that $I_n$ corresponds to $\Pr\left(X_1\leq 0, X_2\leq 0,..., X_n\leq0\right)$ note that
\begin{align}
&\Pr\left(X_1\leq 0, X_2\leq 0,..., X_n\leq0\right)=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0...\int_{-\infty}^0 f(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)dX_n ... dX_2 dX_1 \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0...\int_{-\infty}^0 f(X_1)f(X_2|X_1)...f(X_n|X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1})dX_n...dX_2 dX_1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0...\int_{-\infty}^0 f(X_1)f(X_2|X_1)...f(X_n|X_{n-1})dX_n...dX_2 dX_1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0...\int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(X_1)\phi(X_2-X_1)...\phi(X_n-X_{n-1})dX_n...dX_2 dX_1,
\end{align}
where the last equality uses the observation that $X_k|X_{k-1},X_{k-2},...,X_1=X_k|X_{k-1}\sim N(X_{k-1},1)$

this is related to first passage times, probably well studied.

I agree, I did a quick search before posting and also tried modifying results from study of random walks, but was unable to make a dent. This integral also can arise in sequential analysis in Statistics (which motivates this question). But I could not find any immediately useful references either.

I think the Sparre Andersen theorem implies that the integrals are equivalent to the survival probability of a first passage process. That is, you can replace the gaussians with a random walk.

Write all $\phi'$s as Fourier transforms of their normal distributions with inverse variances. The result is the Fourier transform of of the product, leading to the theorem that convolutions of normal distributions are normal with the sum of means and variances.

doesnt the method of images work here?

@user619894 What is the method of images?

We have$$\begin{align}
I_n &= \mathbb{P}(X_1\le0,..., X_{n-1} \le0,X_n \le 0)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_n\le 0|X_1\le0,..., X_{n-1} \le0)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1\le0,..., X_{n-1} \le0)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(Z_n+X_{n-1}\le 0| X_{n-1} \le0)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1\le0,..., X_{n-1} \le0) \hspace{1cm}\text{Markov property}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Z_n+X_{n-1}\le 0, X_{n-1} \le0)}{\mathbb{P}(X_{n-1} \le0)}\cdot I_{n-1} \\
I_n&=\mathbb{P}(Z_n+X_{n-1}\le 0, X_{n-1} \le0)\cdot 2\cdot I_{n-1} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
It suffices to compute $K:=\mathbb{P}(Z_n+X_{n-1}\le 0, X_{n-1} \le0)$
$$\begin{align}
K &=\mathbb{P}(Z_n + X_{n-1}\le 0, X_{n-1} \le0) \\
&=\mathbb{P}( X_{n-1} \le \min \{0,-Z_n\}) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Phi \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\min \{0,-z\}\right)\varphi(z)dz\\
&= \underbrace{\int_0^{+\infty} \Phi \left(-\frac{z}{\sqrt{n-1}} \right)\varphi(z)dz}_{:=H\left(1/\sqrt{n-1}\right)} + \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^0 \Phi (0)\varphi(z)dz}_{=\Phi^2 (0) = 1/4} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
What we need to compute is $H(x) =\int_0^{+\infty} \Phi (-xz)\varphi(z)dz$ for $x>0$.
Let's try the following technique
$$\begin{align}
H'(x) &= -\int_0^{+\infty} z\varphi (-xz)\varphi(z)dz\\
&=-\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2z^2}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}zdz\\
&=-\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{4\pi}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2+1}{2}z^2}dz^2\\
&=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{(x^2+1)}{2}t}dt\\
&= -\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2 +1}
\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}H(x) &= \underbrace{H(0)}_{=1/4} -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^a\frac{1}{t^2 + 1}dt=\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \arctan(x)\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}&(3)\implies H\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \arctan\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} \right)\\
&(2)\implies K = H\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)  +\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2} -  \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \arctan\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} \right)\\
&(1)\implies \color{red}{ \frac{I_n}{I_{n-1}} = 1- \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot \arctan\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} \right)}
 \end{align}$$
Remark
With Mathematica 12.0, I obtain
$$\begin{align}
&I_1 = \frac{1}{2}\\
&I_2 = \frac{3}{8} = \left(1-\frac{1}{\pi} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\color{red}{1}}} \right)\right)\cdot I_1\\
&I_3 = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \arcsin\left(\sqrt{2/3}\right) + \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right) = \left(1-\frac{1}{\pi} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\color{red}{3}}} \right)\right)\cdot I_2
\end{align}$$
Unable to symbolically calculate $I_4$. $I_4$ is approximatedly equal to $0.2734362491931555$ (but this result is not reliable as the computation is not converged and Mathematica shows some error messages).
@Mdoc: I believe the formula I show, with $\arctan$ function is globally correct. Perhaps there is some typo related to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ that I need your double-check.

Thank you. Your approach makes sense, but I have trouble to reconcile it with my numerical computations. For example, for n=3, I get that $I_3=5/16$ and so $I_3/I_2=5/6\approx 0.833$. However, plugging $n=3$ into the expression in the answer for $I_n/I_{n-1}$ leads to $0.8041$.

Your formula works for $n=2$. But it diverges for $n\geq 3$ from what I get by repeated application of integration by parts and what I obtain using numerical integration in Matlab. But I cannot see an issue in your computation. Maybe the integral does $I_n$ does not correspond to the event that ${X_1<0,X_2<0,...,X_n<0}$? Because your approach to computing the probability of this event seems correct.

I checked really carefully all the steps and computation of $K$ is correct. I get the same answer using Matlab and also this integral appears in tables of Gaussian integrals with exactly the same answer.  So the part I am unsure about is whether $Pr(X_n< 0|X_1<0 0, X_2< 0,...,X_{n-1}<0)$ is indeed equal to $Pr(X_n\leq 0|X_{n-1}<0)$... Clearly, the distribution of $X_n|X_{n-1},X_{n-2},...,X_1$ is equal to $X_n|X_{n-1}$. But is $X_n|X_{n-1}<0,X_{n-2}<0,...,X_1<0$ equal to $X_n|X_{n-1}<0$? I wonder since the realization of $X_{n-2}$ gives us information where the distribution of $X_{n-1}$.

@Mdoc I haven’t found any issue with the conditional expectation you mentionned in the comment just above. I’ll check the calculation numerically today.

@Mdoc I added the Remark.

Mathematica gives a correct answer for $I_3$ since $\arctan(1/\sqrt{3})=\pi/6$ and we obtain $I_3=(5/6) I_2$. This is what I obtain analytically, too. So you are right that there does seem to be an issue with the argument in $\arctan$. I will see if I can find it...

I am totally puzzled here. I cannot see the issue with your computations but at the same time, numerically and analytically (using integration by parts) I obtain different answer... And Mathematica also delivers different answer for $n=3$. I thought maybe the integral does not correspond to the joint probability of the event ${X_1\leq 0,..., X_n\leq 0}$ but I went through it again (added as a Remark at the end of the question) and it seems correct.

@Mdoc I think the error is mine. With Mathematica,
$$$$
Probability[z1 + z2 + z3 <= 0 [Conditioned]z1 <= 0 [And] z1 + z2 <= 0, {z1, z2, z3} [Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[3]]] $$$$
Probability[z1 + z2 + z3 <= 0 [Conditioned]z1 + z2 <= 0, {z1, z2, z3} [Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[3]]]
$$$$
do not give the same result. Don't know why the Markov property does not work here.

Yes, it is strange. I have been thinking that there might be an issue with the Markov property but don't really understand why. And it made me question everything I know about basic probability theory...
